# Basic syntax of comments and docstrings in Python code

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

I'm learning how to use *Sphinx* to create a documentation for my code. After I saw some examples like this:

```py
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    Keyword arguments:
    real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)

    """
    if imag == 0.0 and real == 0.0: return complex_zero
    ...
```

What is the language used in comments to make Sphinx understand and catch them?
Without this syntax and logic, Sphinx doesn't see the comments in my code and when I generate the HTML, the module is empty.

Here an example:

[image: side-by-side documentation compare]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish *comments* from *docstrings* (called "documentation strings" in full).

See [PEP8 and notice *docstrings* apply only to](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) modules, functions, classes, and methods. To the mentioned objects you can apply `your_object.__doc__` to retrieve the docstring programmatically; Variables don't have *docstrings*.

Regarding your example:

```py
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    Keyword arguments:
    real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)

    """
```

There are 3 prevalent syntaxes that can be used in docstring that *Sphinx* will retrieve:

1. reST is the basic syntax.
2. Numpy-style docstrings.
3. Google-style docstrings.

The norm is to choose between *Numpy* or *Google style* (currently they provide better readability and functionality, together with a style guide). For these to work you'll need to use the [Sphinx-Napoleon extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html), take a look at the overview in the official documentation.

Comment: Very nice! I will start to study Numpy style to try aplly in my code. Need any import to use this Numpy style? or sphinx will understand automatic?

Comment: @HenriqueOliveiraCosta Like I said in the post, you need to install Napoleon extension using `pip` and include it in your `conf.py`.