# How to indicate a valid range in a Python docstring using Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

Is there a way to indicate a "valid range" in a Python docstring using Sphinx?  For example, consider the following linear function.

```py
def f(m, x, b):
    """
    Returns the `y` value of a linear function using slope-intercept form.
    
    :param x: The x-axis value.
    :type x: float
    :param m: The slope of the linear function.
    :type m: float
    :param b: The y-intercept.
    :type b: float
    """
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError('The min "x" value of this function is 0')
    return m * x + b
```

Is there a way to indicate the domain of `x` to be something like "x must be greater than zero"?  Or in interval notation, `[0, infinity]`.

Specifically, is there a way to document this in a Python docstring using Sphinx?

Comment: Why not merely append it to the definition? `:param x: The x-axis value. The min "x" value of this function is 0.`

Comment: @StevePiercy I could do that, but I was hoping there might be an option (or something) in Sphinx to add some special formatting to the function's `domain`, so it would be easier to notice when viewing the docs after they were rendered.

Comment: There is no such feature. Autodoc only parses method signatures and docstrings in the Python domain, not arbitrary code.

Comment: Defining a `domain` in an idiomatic Pythonic way would be to define a [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) in the docstring that Sphinx would then render (depending on  sphix-theme) as an admonition. Notice, doctest is a simple Python construct used mostly to express simple cases. For more elaborate use cases you'd implement a `domain` class, document it, and cross-reference it. The key to documentation being consistency, you can verbally say what the domain is using some form of highlight with backticks or bold.

Comment: You may also want to consider the advantages of a [switch from basic ReST syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62545296).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [Python modules are UTF-8](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=encoding#lexical-analysis) encoded so the characters are going to render normally. The string literals can be written using the Unicode character or corresponding [hexadecimal code using the `u`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=encoding#string-and-bytes-literals) prefix in the docstring. This makes the [Unicode range for math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode) available to be written in the docstring.

> Python reads program text as Unicode code points; the encoding of a source file can be given by an encoding declaration and defaults to UTF-8, see PEP 3120 for details.

Example string literals with Unicode characters written both explicitly and with `u` prefix, using a Google style docstring:

```py
def f(m, x, b) -> float:
    """
    Returns the `y` value of a linear function using slope-intercept form.

    Args:
        x (float): The x-axis value.
        m (float): The slope of the linear function.
        b (float): The y-intercept.
    Returns:
        float: The y-axis value.
    Raises:
        ValueError: Value of `x` ∈ [0, ∞], or `x` \u2208\u005B 0, \u221E\u005D.

    """
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError('The min "x" value of this function is 0')
    return m * x + b
```

The result:

[image]

This works fine for simple equations, if you want to write more sophisticated mathematical expressions [Sphinx has several extensions that allow to output them as HTML](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/math.html#module-sphinx.ext.mathbase).