# How to write docstring in Python for a function that returns None but write files in disk?

Tags: python, docstring

I want to use Python docstring to better document my code.

In the function below, it takes a list as input and write a file into disk. I want to know how to document the output of function in docstring as the function return type in None. Does it have a convention?

```
def foo(list_of_items: list) -> None :
    """Simple function.

    Parameters
    ----------
        list_of_items : list of str
        list of some texts    

    Returns
    -------
        what is the best way to write this section?
    """

    file = open('/path/output.txt')
    file.write(list_of_items[1])
    file.close()
```

Comment: I would leave out the "Returns" section, although I don't think there's a universal standard.

Comment: that may depend on what you are using to create your documentation. e.g. sphinx with restructured text?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I use numpy style for documentation

Comment: numpy uses sphinx. i do not know whether they use retext or markdown (or sth else). you might try to find that out (or briefly look at the source code). but have a look at [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/) in any case,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Python convention regarding type hints would be:

> [Non-goals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals), PEP 484
>
> It should also be emphasized that Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.

Considering this, there are [3 syntax for writing docstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62545296). Two syntaxes have their own style guide, see [numpydoc docstring guide](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html) and [Google Python Style Guide - 3.8 Comments and Docstrings](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#s3.8-comments-and-docstrings). (By comparison [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) are not as specific).

The case of functions that only return `None` is not specifically mentioned by numpydoc style guide, carefully notice that it only addressess the case of **functions that return values**:

> [Sections - numpydoc docstring guide](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#sections)
>
> 5. Returns
>
> Explanation of the **returned values** and their types. Similar to the Parameters section, except the name of each return value is optional. The type of **each return value** is always required

Thus In formal Python terms, a function that returns `None` returns no value, because in this situation **`None` signifies the absence of a value**, and so the numpydoc guideline does not mention this special case:

> [3.2. The standard type hierarchy, Data Model](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html)
>
> None
>
> - **This type** has a single value(...) **It is used to signify the absence of a value in many situations, e.g., it is returned from functions that don’t explicitly return anything.**

Since the style guide is omiss, so we can try to search the numpy documentation for a function that returns `None` to see how it's done. A good example is [`numpy.copyto`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html#numpy.copyto) and indeed the **docstring section** corresponding to `Return` is absent.

[image: image of numpy.copyto documentation]

The detailed documentation of a method and its docstring should not to be confused with a listing where a brief textual description might be given. Compare the detailed documentation of the above `numpy.copyto` example with the list in [Logic functions - comparison](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/routines.logic.html#comparison) which does textually describe the returns but omits all type hints from the signatures.

For completeness we can quote the Google style guide on this case:

> [3.8.3 Functions and Methods, Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#383-functions-and-methods)
>
> Returns: (or Yields: for generators)
> (...) If the function only returns None, this section is not required.

Finally, the example in the question can be written with NumPy style docstrings as:

```py
def foo(list_of_items: list, the_path: str) -> None:
    """Simple function writes list_of_items to the_path.

    Parameters
    ----------
        list_of_items : list of str
            Describes list_of_items.
        the_path : str
            Describes the_path.
    """

    file = open(the_path)
    file.write(list_of_items[1])
    file.close()
```

Or with Google style docstrings as:

```py
def foo2(list_of_items: list[str], the_path: str) -> None:
    """Simple function writes list_of_items to the_path.

    Params:
        list_of_items (list[str]): Describes list_of_items.
        the_path (str): Describes the_path.
    """

    file = open(the_path)
    file.write(list_of_items[1])
    file.close()
```

Comment: I think @bad_coder has well argued what the logic of the employed convention is. However, i think that both google style and NumpY style provide a bit to little information here.... if the main output of a function is a file and not a value, why not document the file output similarly to the value output?